# The code below creates spreadsheet (GSheets) and returns a link, but when i tried to open it and edit it i had no permission to do so. Any solutions?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

There is my code:

```
from gspread_asyncio import AsyncioGspreadClientManager
import io
import csv
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from gspread.exceptions import SpreadsheetNotFound

async def upload_file_to_gsheets(credentials_path, csv_string, spreadsheet_name):
    try:

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path,
                                                                            scopes=[
                                                                                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth',
                                                                                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
       
        agcm = AsyncioGspreadClientManager(lambda: credentials)
        
        gc_client = await agcm.authorize()
        
        try:
            spreadsheet = await gc_client.open(spreadsheet_name)
        except SpreadsheetNotFound:

            spreadsheet = await gc_client.create(spreadsheet_name)
        .
        worksheet = await spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)

        
        csv_file = io.StringIO(csv_string)
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        values_list = list(reader)

        
        await worksheet.update('A1', values_list)
        
        spreadsheet_url = spreadsheet.url
        return spreadsheet_url

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return
```

It returns link to created spreadsheet; but when i tried to read it i have no permisson to do so. How can i fix this issue? Should I change the access settings in Google Cloud Console or can this be done using code?

I tried to change permissions on https://console.cloud.google.com, but it didn't work. Also i tried to delete and create keys again (also didn't work). How can i fix this problem? I'm new to python and Google Drive and Goggle Sheets API's. Pls, help :)

Answer (score 0):

How i solved my problem:

```
 # Asynchronously create and initialize the Google Drive API client.
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    # Define the new permission.
    user_permission = {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'writer',  # 'owner' is not allowed for service accounts.
        'emailAddress': 'example.com'  # Email of the user to share with.
    }

    # Grant the defined permission.
    drive_service.permissions().create(
        fileId=spreadsheet.id,
        body=user_permission,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
    return spreadsheet_url
```